# Validation issues with polymer's new paper-input / paper-input-decorator components

Tags: validation, polymer, paper-elements

Following the recent changes to paper-input and the introduction of paper-input-decorator (polymer v0.5.1), I'm now having trouble implementing input validation.  For instance, prior to the recent changes I had constructed a custom 'property-editor' polymer element (i.e. an element that essentially combines a configurable icon, a configurable input control (type paper-dropdown-menu or regular input), and an associated optional unit value entry control (type paper-dropdown-menu or paper-input)), and it was very functional.  Here is a small subset of code showing one of the templates within the aforementioned custom element, that activated when a regular expression pattern was provided to it.  This was working well:

```
<template if="{{controlType == 'input' && controlValidPattern != null}}">
     <paper-input id="{{controlId}}" value="{{inputValue}}" label="{{controlLabel}}" floatingLabel="{{controlFloatingLabel}}" pattern="{{controlValidPattern}}" error="{{controlErrorMsg}}" required="{{controlInputRequired}}" maxlength="{{controlMaxLength}}">
     </paper-input> 
</template>
```

Then I had implemented an `inputValueChanged` watcher function, which in turn fired a custom event for the host/consuming element to act on as required.

The end goal is of course to display the validation error message for the control when the current input is invalid (which can occur 'live' as the user types, and could be present when the control is loaded with the initial input value), or even better prevent the user from entering invalid data in the first place.  In any case, the 'inputValueChanged' function should be prevented from firing unless the input is valid, and also not fire that event until the user leaves the control (on blur etc.).  I've been playing around a little bit trying to get this to work again using the new versions of the paper elements (see example attempt below), but still having some difficulty.  Can anyone kindly provide an example that achieves regular expression pattern matching, with the desired behaviors described above?

```
<template if="{{controlType == 'input' && controlValidPattern != null}}">
     <paper-input-decorator label="{{controlLabel}}" floatingLabel="{{controlFloatingLabel}}" error="{{controlErrorMsg}}" isInvalid="{{invalidEntry}}">
          <input is="core-input" id="{{controlId}}" value="{{inputValue}}" committedValue="{{committedValue}}" pattern="{{controlValidPattern}}" maxlength="{{controlMaxLength}}" required="{{controlInputRequired}}" size="{{controlWidth}}">
     </paper-input-decorator> 
</template>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice/example you can lend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate the input as the input value changes, the `isInvalid` property on `paper-input-decorator` should be bound to the input's `validity.valid` property. ie.

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <paper-input-decorator label="Number" floatingLabel
                         error="is not a number" 
                         isInvalid="{{!$.input.validity.valid}}">
    <input id="input" is="core-input" pattern="\d*">
  </paper-input-decorator>
</template>
```

To answer the comment below, if you don't have the id of the input in advance, you can listen for the `input` event and set `isInvalid` in the handler:

In this case you can listen for the input event and set `isInvalid` in the handler:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <paper-input-decorator id="decorator" label="Number" floatingLabel
                     error="is not a number">
    <input is="core-input" pattern="\d*" on-input="{{inputAction}}">
  </paper-input-decorator>
</template>
<script>
  var scope = document.querySelector('template[is=auto-binding]');
  scope.inputAction = function(e) {
    var d = document.getElementById('decorator');
    d.isInvalid = !e.target.validity.valid;
  }
</script>
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/hocugi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Yvonne.  This might be a simple question to answer, but when the 'id' of the input itself is generated programmatically (provided via moustache expression), how would one access that .validity.valid property?

Comment: Ok, I'm on the right track now...except...is there a way to utilize 'preventInvalidInput' with the decorator to not allow a user to enter a character that would create a non-match to the regular expression pattern?

Comment: `preventInvaildInput` is a property on the `core-input`, so it should just work?

Comment: Your first one does not work for me, but the second one. The problem is: how do I validate more than one input? I could use different IDs but that's a worst case scenario. Do you have a solution for that? getElementByID has always the same element^^

Comment: @YvonneYip I extended your second solution to get more than just one input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194592/multiple-validation-of-paper-elements-in-polymer/28196451#28196451

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on to Yvonne's provided answer, I thought I'd post a couple of snippets of fixed code from the custom component I referred to in the original post, now utilizing paper-input-decorators, both with specified input type(s), regular expression pattern etc.:

```
<template if="{{controlType == 'input' && controlEntryType != null}}">
     <paper-input-decorator label="{{controlLabel}}" floatingLabel="{{controlFloatingLabel}}" value="{{inputValue}}" error="{{controlErrorMsg}}">
           <input is="core-input" id="{{controlId}}" type="{{controlEntryType}}" value="{{inputValue}}" committedValue="{{committedValue}}" step="{{controlNumberStep}}" min="{{controlNumberMin}}" max="{{controlNumberMax}}" on-input="{{inputAction}}" maxlength="{{controlMaxLength}}" required="{{controlInputRequired}}" size="{{controlWidth}}">
     </paper-input-decorator>
</template>

<template if="{{controlType == 'input' && controlValidPattern != null}}">
     <paper-input-decorator label="{{controlLabel}}" floatingLabel="{{controlFloatingLabel}}" value={{inputValue}} error="{{controlErrorMsg}}">
           <input is="core-input" id="{{controlId}}" pattern="{{controlValidPattern}}" preventInvalidInput value="{{inputValue}}" committedValue="{{committedValue}}" on-input="{{inputAction}}" maxlength="{{controlMaxLength}}" required="{{controlInputRequired}}" size="{{controlWidth}}">
     </paper-input-decorator>
</template>

<template if="{{controlType == 'input' && controlEntryType == null && controlValidPattern == null}}">
     <paper-input-decorator label="{{controlLabel}}" floatingLabel="{{controlFloatingLabel}}" value="{{inputValue}}" error="{{controlErrorMsg}}">
           <input is="core-input" id="{{controlId}}" type="text" value="{{inputValue}}" committedValue="{{committedValue}}" on-input="{{inputAction}}"  maxlength="{{controlMaxLength}}" required="{{controlInputRequired}}" size="{{controlWidth}}">
     </paper-input-decorator>
</template>

inputAction: function(e, detail, sender) {
    // Reset paper-input-decorator's validity based on current user input
    sender.parentElement.isInvalid = !sender.validity.valid;
},

committedValueChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    /* Event designed to listen for paper-input value changes */

    // When the input is valid, fire a custom event that can be listened to by the host element (i.e. via 'on-property-change')
    // Pass to the listener an object representing the property that was changed by this element

    if(this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#" + this.controlId).validity.valid) {
            this.fire('property-change', {newProperty: this.propertyChanged()});
    }
},
```